# How to open a ansible include_task file in a role using vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible

In our ansible role ,there is a main file which calls tasks from multiple files.
One of the sample task is given below

```
- name: Delete folder
  include_tasks: folder_delete.yml
  vars:
     folder: "{{folder_name}}"
```

If i need to go to the file folder_delete.yml thne currently i am copying the file name folder_delete then use `Ctrl+p` then in it i am copying and open the file.

In other languages , If we click on function and click f12 ,it will go to definition. Like that in ansible extension ,is there any way to go to the file by using some shortcut? I am opening files many times, a shortcut will be a great help

Or is there a way to write that in some macro ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by myself but recording it for future user.

I used the `Openfileatcursor` extension . I select the file and type `alt+d` then it shows it in quick open. From there i am able to open it. This helps me a lot.

Also another extension named `Openfile` . This is even more useful, I have to select the file name and type `Alt+p` it will open the file